# Can't open Android Studio after increasing memory

Tags: android, memory, emulation

I got the common error ""Execution failed for task app:dexDebug"." when trying to run my app, and it seems like it's got nothing to do with the settings in the Gradle files, because I can open a smaller project which has the exact same settings.

So I guess it's because my project is too big. I tried to increase the memory capacity of Android Studio by editing the file 'studio64.exe.vmoptions', but after this, I cannot open the program at all! Any help?

Comment: According to the Android Studio documentation you can't modify the `studio64.exe.vmoptions` directly. See the docs http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration. In this case, you will need back to the old configuration before. What is the `studio64.exe.vmoptions` configuration that you have ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried changing the variable back to 256, and now I can open the program again, but still, I can't run the app.. Configurations:


-Xms256m

-Xmx1280m

-XX:MaxPermSize=350m

-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=225m

-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC

-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50

-ea

-Djna.nosys=true

-Djna.boot.library.path=



-Djna.debug_load=true

-Djna.debug_load.jna=true

-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false

-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

-Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudio1.3

-Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio

Comment: Sorry for the lack of lining, but it seems like I can't add linespaces here.

Comment: Have you tried changing the project to a multidex application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems with startup and configuration files associated with Android Studio (AS). This can break up the normal AS initialization mode.

So, try some of these steps:

**1) Use another `studio64.exe.vmoptions` file**

This is my default `studio64.exe.vmoptions` used with AS **stable version 1.5**. Pay attention for this. In his case, you are using 1.3 version, so you need change for appropriate version.

---

```
#
# *DO NOT* modify this file directly. If there is a value that you would like to override,
# please add it to your user specific configuration file.
#
# See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration
#
-server
-Xms256m
-Xmx750m
-XX:MaxPermSize=350m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=150m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-da
-Djna.nosys=true
-Djna.boot.library.path=

-Djna.debug_load=true
-Djna.debug_load.jna=true
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudio1.5
-Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio
```

**2) Try to delete .idea files**

If the step 1) not succeeded, so you can delete some AS directories such as **.idea** and **.gradle**. Pay attention, **only delete these files if you make a backup from his project before**.

**3) Install a new Android Studio version**

If the previous steps was not performed successfully, so I recommend you to install AS again in another folder and checkout his projects again.